# xenserver vm import: what arguments pass to xe vm-import command in remote-config=

Tags: vmware, xen

I wants to import vm from vmware to xenserver using xenserver conversion manager using xe command"

**xe vm-import filename='' force=true host-password=<>  host-username=<>  preserve=false remote-config= ? sr-uuid=<> type=ESXServer**

you can also see the command using **xe help vm-import**.

But I don't know what arguments pass in remote-config=

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following two options directly answer your question as they are the shortest paths.

1. From VMWare, export your desired VM to a shared disk (or your desktop) -- making sure the output is in OVF format.  From XenCenter, use the import utility: browsing to your shared disk and selecting the OVF file in question.
2. Depending on your version of XenServer there exists a virtual appliance to assist with pulling in VMs from VMware/VSphere.  These are licensed options for the record, so opensource XenServer will not facilitate the functions of these solutions.

I will focus on XenServer 6.5, which download resources can be found at:

http://www.citrix.com/downloads/xenserver/product-software/xenserver-65.html

You will want to browse to the bottom of the page for "Optional Components" and download the XenServer Conversion Manager VPX 6.5.0 and/or Console tool for batch conversion.

After importing the appliance, the documentation on using it can be found in the [Administration Guide](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX141500).

From VMware, the VM should be exported to OVF form